# groupby function on a calculated column

Tags: group-by, pyspark

I am joining multiple dataframes
and I am calculating the output by multiplying two columns from two diff dataframes and dividing it with a column belonging to another dataframe.
I get grouping sequence expression is empty error and no_order is not an aggregate function
whats is wrong with the code

```
df = df1.join(df2,df2["Code"] == df1["Code"],how = 'left')\
.join(df3, df3["ID"] == df1["ID"],how = 'left')\
.join(df4, df4["ID"] == df1["ID"],how = 'left')\
.join(df5, df5["Scenario"] == df1["Status"],how='left')\
.withColumn("Country",when(df1.Ind == 1,"WI"))\
.withColumn("Country",when(df1.Ind == 0,"AA"))\
.withColumn("Year",when(df1.Year == "2020","2021"))\
.agg((sum(df5["amt"] * df1["cost"]))/df2["no_order"]).alias('output')
.groupby('Country','Year','output')
```

Answer (score 0):

the error shows you that df2["no_order"] should be withing some aggregation function, for example the sum which you are using for df5["amt"] * df1["cost"].
Also move .groupby() above .agg().

If I got correctly what you are trying to achieve, the code should look like:

```
df = df1\
.join(df2, on = 'Code', how = 'left')\
.join(df3, on = 'ID', how = 'left')\
.join(df4, on = 'ID', how = 'left')\
.join(df5, df5.Scenario == df1.Status, how='left')\
.withColumn('Country', when(df1.Ind == 1,"WI").when(df1.Ind == 0,"AA"))\
.withColumn('Year', when(df1.Year == "2020","2021"))\
.groupby('Country','Year')\
.agg(sum(df5["amt"] * df1["cost"] / df2["no_order"]).alias('output'))
```